# No changes shown in vscode source control tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab, vscode-remote

I cloned a repository from gitlab to vscode and I configure gitlab using the commands as follow:

```
git config --global user.name ***

git config --global user.email ***
```

No changes shown in the source control  tab in vscode to commit them.

> Git status:
>
> On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
> Nothing to commit, working  tree clean

Comment: did you tried to reinstall vscode or git ?

Comment: Have you changed any of the code? What does `git status` show? Global git config is not stored in the repository.

Comment: Yes i've tried that also but not working

Comment: @CodeSpirityes I changed my code but nothing shown

Comment: @CodeSpirit I tried also git --version and itvis fine

Comment: @Hsn What "yes"? Please add git status output to question.

Comment: I am on the master branch on my giltab repository

Comment: @Hsn Are you working locally or in the cloud?

Comment: @CodeSpiritI added the status to my question

Comment: @Hsn Your output shows that you have not changed any files in the index. Are the files you have changed ignored by `.gitignore`? Please learn how to use git first.

Comment: @CodeSpirit I working locally on my pc folders

Comment: @CodeSpirit I changed the code and the status still the same

Comment: @CodeSpirit the .gitignore contains: /docs/ /sync/ /sync_/ /config/

Comment: What is the name and path of the file you edited? do you have more than one .gitignore? Git uses all .gitignores in all parent folders of the file you edited to determine whether the file is indexed or not.